# what's the meaning of "It is not without interest that"?

Tags: meaning

what's the meaning of "It is not without interest that"?

e.g.
It is not without interest that most of the reports of military campaigns and 
the scenes of destruction of towns are dated to the late Fifth and the early Sixth 
Dynasty, that is, the final stage of the Old Kingdom.

Answer (score 4):

It means that it's of **some** interest.

Comment: Yes: the amount of interest is greater than zero. Perhaps [*litotes*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litotes) is worth a mention too.

Comment: Litotes is not without relevance.

Answer (score 3):

You could replace *It is not without interest* with *It's interesting*. I'm assuming the author was telling you that he wasn't ignoring the fact that "most of the reports of military campaigns and the scenes of destruction of towns are dated to the late Fifth and the early Sixth Dynasty," even though that may not be the main focus of the piece.

Answer (score 1):

*It is with interest that most of the report*....

Curious enough the use of two negatives together, *not* and *without* that elide each other to give a positive meaning to the sentence. May create confusion, but it attracts the attention of readers.